# Hokuyo_node single scan mode

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is it possible to configure the hokuyo_node to produce a scan at a specified time, as in single scan mode? As i understand the current default configuration is continuous scan mode where the node continuously publishes laser scans in the topic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58057/hokuyo_node-single-scan-mode/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there are no such settings, but you can subscribe to the laser topic and pick out the frame you want. Timestamp is stored in header of the topic message. See
[LaserScan message](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)
for details.

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1